# Gnome terminal is not snapping back to original size in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

When I hold and drag GNOME Terminal 3.18.3 [available with ubuntu 16.04] to top of screen to maximize it does that beautifully. But when i do the same for it to restore back to original size by pulling it down, it doesnot restore back to the original size. The window remains maximum size although the title bar snaps out of the unity top bar.

But i donot have similar issue the `terminator`.